# Catching Internal Server Error in Ajax GET request

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, get

I'm writing a little AJAX script that is just meant to grab an SVG file and load it inline into the doc. It works perfectly, as long as the file that's being called is present, but I'm trying to test for the possibility that of a file not found. I can't seem to catch the error in a way that prevents a 500 Internal Server error that prevents the rest of the script from being executed.

Here's the code pared down to only relevent parts:

```
  function loadSvg(selector, url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(req, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
      },
      statusCode: {
        500: function() {
          console.log("This executes when present, otherwise error executes. Either way, fatal error.");
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Both `statusCode` and `error` execute just fine. But even when they execute, it still doesn't prevent the 500 error:

[error console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB4mI.png)

How do I prevent this from erroring out?

Comment: Im not sure if this could help but would wrapping it in a case statement work?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean. Aren't success and error essentially built-in case statements? Are you suggesting maybe testing for the existence of the file and only then calling AJAX if it exists? Seem redundant to me, when AJAX should be handling that itself, but maybe I'm misunderstanding.